# opencpu server, how to implement OAuth2 interface?

Tags: r, github, oauth-2.0, opencpu

I have installed an OpenCPU server and am trying to let users create their own logins but I  keep on getting the following error message:

```
GET /auth/login
Github secret file not found.
```

Any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `auth/login` endpoint is related to the (experimental) github authentication. For this to work, you need to create a file on the system named `/etc/opencpu/secret.conf` containing the github 'secret', which is sort of a private key. The `secret.conf` file must be formatted like this:

```
{
  "secret": "1515ab906aa1c8250e99410fb204a8d3fd16a738"
}
```

For more info on github authentication and registering your domain to get a secret, see http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/.

On a side note: if you are hosting your own server, it might be easier to ssh-in as root and install R packages you would like to use in the standard lcoations. These packages will then become available under `/R/pub` e.g: http://public.opencpu.org/R/pub.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, when I registered for a new clientId and secret-file on GitHub, it asked for a URL and Callback URL. Any idea what to use for these two URLs. for example my website is "http://myopencpu.saurk.edu/R"  Also I intend to wrap my R function as an "app" but don't know how to go about it, is there an easy to follow example or tutorial for it ?